# What does 'Did they suspect she was here?' mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence, questions

I'm curious about what this sentence means?

> Did they suspect she was here?

Does that mean they suspect the truth of that she was here? or they thought "She was here! You just lied to us that she was **not** here."

Comment: It's really just a question regarding whether or not they thought she might be there.

Answer (score 2):

The latter. The former is doubt.

Comment: +1.  *Did they suspect that she had not been here?* could be the thought of someone who said that she had been there, who thinks people may suspect he is lying.